# jQuery Mobile Remove the icon disc background in select

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm writing my first jQuery Mobile app with PhoneGap/Cordova, and although I've had a few hiccups styling it just how I want, I've managed quite well.

That's until I came across forms. When I set a select element using jQuery, is there any way to remove the disc background of the icon? I tried assigning a class of `ui-nodisc-icon` to the element, but it's not working.

I'm thinking of using my own icon implementation with FontAwesome, but I'd like to know if there's a way to do it directly with JQM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add it to `div` wrapping `select` menu. There is no *static* solution for this, as jQM wraps `select` in a div upon widget enhancement.

```
$("#selectID").closest("div").addClass("ui-nodisc-icon");
```

Comment: Omar is correct. If you want to apply this to all selects and make the icon dark so it shows better without the disk: $(".ui-select .ui-btn").addClass("ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon"); Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/nqXLp/

Comment: The extra div worked perfectly. Currently I'm only targeting a couple of elements, but the tip from @ezanker is also good. I always try to avoid unnecessary markup, but after working with JQM for a few days I'm starting to realize this will not be possible.

Comment: @carlos by time you'll get to know JQM and reveal its' tricks :)