# Jquery Mobile 1.4.2 CSS: Button styling without overridding jQuery css elements

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am noticing that in jQuery 1.4.2, styling items has become incredibly hard. It appears as if I am no longer able to style anything other than the supplied jQuery Mobile css. For example:

```
<input id="PlaceLocationButton" enableviewstate="true" onclick="Click()" type="button" value="Set Location" class="map_button top_row_map_button" runat="server" data-inline="true" />

.top_row_map_button{
    width: 15em !important;
}
```

It doesn't matter if I make the width 15 or 15,00000 the button size will not change until I alter the `ui-btn` class itself. this makes styling single buttons almost impossible unless I take the jQuery route, which is very unideal. I understand the reason for this (the button styles are applied in a parent div created by jQuery Mobile), but there has to be a way to style the button itself correct? What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit** Some other failed attempts:

```
<div class="top_row_map_button">
    <input id="PlaceLocationButton" enableviewstate="true" onclick="ClickGeocode()" type="button"
        value="Set Location" class="map_button" runat="server" data-inline="true" />
</div>

.top_row_map_button:nth-child(2){
    width: 15em !important;
}

.top_row_map_button:nth-child(1){
    width: 15em !important;
}

.top_row_map_button {
    width: 15em !important;
}
```

Again, nothing unless I style the div element generated by jQuery Mobile, which I cannot do because I do not have access to that element before the page is loaded (unless I style the classes in css, which I am trying to avoid)

Comment: `input` is wrapped in a div, apply styles to that div not `input` itself as it'll be hidden. similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/23090903/1771795

Comment: How can I do that though? I cannot put an id on that div because I do not create it. The only way for me to do that would be to style the jQM css classes, which will cause issues with the rest of the buttons on my page

Comment: use id of `input` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/LX3Rg/

Comment: I noticed you were using javascript to add the style. So I am guessing that is what will be required with jQuery mobile? I can do that if need be, but it would be nice to have a css style that I could apply.

Comment: JS is required here, CSS can't solve it on its own. Another option is to create your own `input` and add `data-role=none` to `input` in order not to be enhanced by jQM.

Comment: Ok. Well I want the enhancements so I will have to live with it. The parent().addClass() solution is the best I've got. Post the fiddle as an answer and Ill accept it

Comment: For a CSS only version of Omar's solution put the button in a containing SPAN, apply the class to the SPAN and make the width rule apply to children of the span with the class .ui-btn: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/LX3Rg/3/

Comment: Also, you can try the data-wrapper-class attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/LX3Rg/4/

Comment: @ezanker Thank you for the `data-wrapper-class`. That was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who find this post in the Future ezanker provided a good solution (comments) by using a `data-wrapper-class`.

```
<input id="PlaceLocationButton" enableviewstate="true" onclick="Click()" type="button" value="Set Location 1" data-inline="true" data-wrapper-class="top_row_map_button" />

.top_row_map_button {
    width: 15em;
}
```

Here is his [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/LX3Rg/4/).